# How to logout from magmi

Tags: magento, magmi

[image]

I have setup magmi but can't find logout option.
And how to secure this page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

**Restrict access by IP-address**

***Apache***

Add the following lines on top of /magmi/.htaccess and /magmi/web/.htaccess files:

`Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from <your_ip>`

***Nginx***

Ask your hosting support or server admin to allow access to /magmi/ location for your IP address only. Sample code to apply in nginx configuration file:

`location /magmi/ {
  allow <your_ip>;
  deny all;
  # other code, depending on your config and the way of passing requests to PHP
  # usually the same as for / location
}`

***Restrict access by additional password protection***

Create password protection file under var/ directory, i.e. var/.htpwd. Use htpasswd command on your server.

***Apache***

Add the following lines on top of /magmi/.htaccess file:

`AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted"
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/magento/var/.htpwd
Require valid-user`

***Nginx***

Ask your hosting support or server admin to allow access to /magmi/ location by password protection. Sample code to apply in nginx configuration file:

`location /magmi/ {
  auth_basic           "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file /path/to/your/magento/var/.htpwd;
  # other code, depending on your config and the way of passing requests to PHP
  # usually the same as for / location
}`

Source: http://magehost.com/blog/securing-magmi-data-import-tool/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot logout from Magmi because you never actually login.

In order to secure access to it you can add something like this on magmi head.php file (magmi/web/head.php)

> After session_start();

```
function authenticate($username=”“,$password=”“){ 
    require "../../app/Mage.php"; 
    Mage::app('default'); 
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user'); 
    $user->login($username,$password); 
    $result = $user->getId(); 
    return $result ? true : false; 
} 

if (!isset($_SERVER[‘PHP_AUTH_USER’])) { 
    header('WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Magmi"'); 
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized'); 
    echo 'You must be logged in to use Magmi'; 
    die(); 
} else { 
if (!authenticate($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'],$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])){
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Magmi"'); 
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized'); 
    echo 'You must be logged in to use Magmi'; 
    die(); 
} 

} 
/***************** *********************/
```

And then use the username/password you have on your magento installation to login.